# How to get latlngs values after edit a polygon in Leaflet-Geoman?

Tags: typescript, leaflet, leaflet-geoman

Suppose I have a geojson data:

```
let featureCollection: GeoJSON.FeatureCollection<any> = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: 'Polygon',
        coordinates: [
          [
            [103.80689620971681, 1.3101770944467952],
            [103.86285781860352, 1.3494769612490358],
            [103.916072845459,   1.2942167094566774],
            [103.86972427368165, 1.2540578798674866],
            [103.87229919433594, 1.3084609288747733],
            [103.83796691894533, 1.2660712704472294],
          ],
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I tried to load that geojson value into a map and integrated with event handlers:

```
L.geoJSON(featureCollection, {
  onEachFeature: (feature: any, layer: L.Layer) => {
    layer.on('pm:edit', (e) => {
      console.log('loaded geojson - pm:edit', e);
    });
    layer.on('pm:rotateend', (e) => {
      console.log('loaded geojson - pm:rotateend', e.originLatLngs, e.newLatLngs);
    });
    map.addLayer(layer);
  },
});
```

Then I modified a polygon by selecting "Edit Layer" from toolbar UI, the browser will trigger `pm:edit` event:

[image: See image]

The debug console will print something like this:

[image: Console output]

**The problem is:** On `pm:edit` event, I didn't find any method to get coordinates of latitude and longitude due to TypeScript restriction, but the console showed `_latlngs` values (see output image). Moreover, some other events like `pm:rotateend` were able to support methods to get coordinate

**What I want is**: How to get the values of latitude and longitude on `pm:edit` event?

Edit: The `leaflet` version is ^1.7.1, `@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free` version is ^2.11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `pm:edit` event you have the `layer` in the payload. From it you can use `toLatLngs()`:

```
layer.on('pm:edit', (e) => {
   console.log(e.layer.getLatLngs())
});
```

**BUT** you will have a Problem with TypeScript because `e.layer` is from type `L.Layer` so you need first to cast / get the instance of the layer:

```
layer.on('pm:edit', (e) => {
  if(e.shape === 'Polygon'){
     (e.layer as Polygon).getLatLngs();
  }
});
```

More infos here: https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman/issues/945